# how to use my documentation comments in the my projects like android documentation?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, documentation

I build documentation comments for my project's source code as a library. and how to use them like android documentation in the new project that use of that library?

Comment: Could you rephrase that as something that ... makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the way of generating the HTML from your javadoc comments in Eclipse and this post may contain the answer: http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2010/02/android-generate-javadoc-for-your.html

Answer (score 2):

As per what i understand from your question i think you can do like this

wherever you want to document something keep below formate on top of the methode,or variable or any class. and whenever you next time take your mouse to that method or variable or class you will get it like document.

```
/**
* getDocument() method gives you 
* @parameter String USerID
* @return String 
*/
public String Document(int UserID) throws Exception
{
return documentString;
}
```

Here for the formate part you have to write everything.as in above e.g. @parameter, @return etc.

Comment: what difference does this comment have with another comments?

Comment: while using normal comment you want find the comment when you take you mose to the above method but with this you can get written comment wherever the above method used.

Comment: could you introduce me a sample link?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for javadoc which generates HTML documentation page from your comments (if your comments follow the javadoc format). Here  is link about [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Comment: yes, my comments are to javadoc format, but i want to after generate HTML documentation I want to use them like android documentation!

Comment: If I understand 'use them like android documentation', all you need to do is, pack these HTMLs part of your software. Otherwise please elaborate that sentence.

Comment: certainly, it's truth. you've got it.